# Dynamically modify RouteValueDictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

As a followup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13382175/1324019), I'm trying to implement a custom route constraint in order to dynamically modify the `RouteValueDictionary` for a specific route.

I'm 95% of the way there: I can match any route based on the supplied parameter pattern matching the action specified in the url. The very last step of this process is to overwrite the RouteValueDictionary to rename the keys as the appropriate parameters for the controller action.

Here's the relevant snippet of my code (the entire class is almost 300 lines so I don't want to add all of it, but I can if needed):

```
public class CustomRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string paramName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (routeDirection.Equals(RouteDirection.UrlGeneration)) {
            return false;
        }

        //this will grab all of the "actual" parameters out of the RVD, excluding action and controller 
        Dictionary<string, object> unMappedList = values.Where(x => x.Key.Contains("param")).OrderBy(xi => xi.Key).ToDictionary(
            kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

        string controller = values["controller"] as string;
        string action = values["action"] as string;

        //this method tries to find the controller using reflection
        Type cont = TryFindController(controller);

        if (cont != null) {
            MethodInfo actionMethod = cont.GetMethod(action);

            if (actionMethod != null) {
                ParameterInfo[] methodParameters = actionMethod.GetParameters();

                //this method validates that the parameters of the action that was found match the expected parameters passed in the custom constraint; it also performs type conversion
                if (validateParameters(methodParameters, unMappedList)) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < methodParameters.Length; i++) {
                        values.First(x => x.Key == unMappedList.ElementAt(i).Key).Key = methodParameters.ElementAt(i).Name; 
                        //above doesn't work, but even if it did it wouldn't do the right thing

                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And here's how I use the custom constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default2",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{param1}-{param2}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { lang = new CustomRouteConstraint(new RoutePatternCollection( new List<ParamType> { ParamType.INT, ParamType.INT })) }
);
```

(What I'm passing into the constructor is basically saying "The parameter pattern to look for is two integers". So when the `Match` method is called, it will return true if the action specified in the url has two two integer parameters, regardless of the actual parameter names.)

So, is there a way I can overwrite the RouteValueDictionary for this request? Or is there some other way I can do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Not an expert on ASP.NET MVC, but I wonder if the route dictionary is a shared resource, either `static` in C#, or `Shared` in VB.NET? If so, then chances are you need to use locking when you modify it, as other requests may be trying to read it at the same time you're changing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I do understand correctly what is the question:

> So, is there a way I can overwrite the RouteValueDictionary for this
>   request? Or is there some other way I can do this that I'm missing?

I've taken your solution and changed these lines to replace parameter names:

```
for (int i = 0; i < methodParameters.Length; i++)
{
    // I. instead of this

    //values.First(x => x.Key == unMappedList.ElementAt(i).Key)
    //    .Key = methodParameters.ElementAt(i).Name; 
    //above doesn't work, but even if it did it wouldn't do the right thing

    // II. do this (not so elegant but working;)
    var key = unMappedList.ElementAt(i).Key;
    var value = values[key];
    values.Remove(key);
    values.Add(methodParameters.ElementAt(i).Name, value);

    // III. THIS is essential! if statement must be moved after the for loop
    //return true;
}
return true; // here we can return true
```

**NOTE:** I like your approach. Sometimes it is simply much more important to extend/adjust routing then go to code and "fix incorrect parameter names". And of course, they are most likely NOT incorrect.

And here is the power of Separation of concern.

- Url addresses are one place.
- Controller, action and parameter names other one.
- And Routing with powerful customization...

...as the only correct place where to handle that. This is separation of concern. Not tweaking the action names to serve Url...

Comment: Argh...I had no idea it was that simple! The error I got said "collection is readonly" so I assumed that any modification of any kind wouldn't work = clearly a bad assumption. Anyway, it works like a charm - I'll post the entire code to my solution on my other question. Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily restrict the parameters to positive integers with a regular expression:

```
private const string IdRouteConstraint = @"^\d+$";

routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default2",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{param1}-{param2}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" },
   constraints: new { param1 = IdRouteConstraint, param2 = IdRouteConstraint});
```

As I said in my answer to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382175/route-patterns-vs-individual-routes), you shouldn't worry about the parameter names in the controller actions. Giving those overly meaningful names will tie you in knots.